# Dark caller ID picture for incoming call

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, caller-id

Why does incoming caller ID picture is dark while outcoming call picture is full brightness? Is it some reason for it? Can I fix it? I find it annoying especially outdoors where the screen is pretty dim already.

Phone: BQ Aquaris M5 with android 5.1.1.

[image: Incoming vs outcoming caller ID]

Answer (score 0):

Connection status may be the reason: dark picture for not established connection (incoming call not answered yet) and bright picture for established connection on your side (incoming call answered or outcoming call). Android 6.0.1 has the same configuration and it seems can't be changed through stock software.